# Unable to load more than one row using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to fetch the data from firebase, using firebaseRecyclerAdapter. But I am unable to populate all the data from the firebase database to the RecyclerView.
Database is as follows:

[image: Firebase Database]

**The output I am getting is only from the "qqq" row**

rvlist Class:

```
public class rvlist {
String name, propellant;

public rvlist() {
}

public rvlist(String name, String propellant) {
    this.name = name;
    this.propellant = propellant;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getPropellant() {
    return propellant;
    }
}
```

MyViewHolder:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
View mView;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mView = itemView;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    TextView field = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.a);
    field.setText(name);
}

public void setPropellant(String text) {
    TextView field = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.b);
    field.setText(text);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference mRef;
RecyclerView rv;
ProgressBar pb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvv);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("table");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<rvlist, MyViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<rvlist, MyViewHolder>
            (rvlist.class, R.layout.model, MyViewHolder.class, mRef) {
        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(MyViewHolder itemsViewHolder, rvlist items, int position) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            itemsViewHolder.setName(items.getName());
            itemsViewHolder.setPropellant(items.getPropellant());
        }
    };
    rv.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is...? [ask]

Comment: have you found the solution for this? I'm getting the same problem

Comment: Check out your row layout for recycler view. It's height should be wrap_content (or specified if any specific) and not match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your RecyclerView and adapter layout_height is set to ***wrap_content*** not to match_parent

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recv_location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        ...>
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```